# Why changes in attached object does not have an effect?

Tags: r

The following example shows that even `x` is changed after it is attached, the value `a` is not changed. Does `attach()` make a copy of the object `x`? Is there a way to mutate the `x` saved by `attach()`?

```
R> x=list(a=1,b=2)
R> attach(x)
R> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "x"                 "package:stats"    
 [4] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
 [7] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"        
[10] "package:base"     
R> x$a=2
R> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "x"                 "package:stats"    
 [4] "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
 [7] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"        
[10] "package:base"     
R> a
[1] 1
R>
```

Comment: From `?attach`, *"The database is not actually attached. Rather, a new environment is created on the search path and the elements of a list (including columns of a data frame) or objects in a save file or an environment are copied into the new environment. If you use <<- or assign to assign to an attached database, you only alter the attached copy, not the original object. (Normal assignment will place a modified version in the user's workspace: see the examples.) For this reason attach can lead to confusion."*.

Comment: @nrussell, post as answer?

Comment: I think the question could probably just be deleted; all the information is right in the documentation. If you disagree, please feel free to write up an answer.

Comment: ...which just brings us to the standard recommendation: *don't use `attach`*.

Answer (score 2):

When we `attach(x)` that creates a new entry on the search list called `x` but the variable `x` still refers to the original list that is in the workspace.  Thus if we assign to `x$a` we are assigning to the original `x` in the workspace, not to the new entry on the search list. Even if we remove that original list `x` the syntax `x$a` cannot be used to refer to `a` in the new entry on the search list; however, there are alternatives which will work.  First start a new R session to ensure that there is no residual junk.  Then try this:

```
# define a list and attach it
x <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
attach(x)

# a few different ways of assigning to a in x on the search list


# 1
assign("a", 99, "x")
a
## [1] 99

# 2
env_x <- as.environment("x")
env_x$a <- 100
a
## [1] 100

# 3
a <<- 200
a
## [1] 200
env_x$a
## [1] 200

# the a in the original list x is unchanged
x$a
## [1] 1
```

This is sufficiently confusing and bothersome that the usual advice is just not to use `attach` in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately, `attach()` is used in `attachNamespace()`, which is in turn called by `library()`. If `attach()` should not be used, should `library()` resorts to a better way to expose external packages?

Comment: This was referring to the user using it directly.

Comment: Could you comment on the usage of `<<-`? It is not clear to me how it find `env_v$a` with just `a`.

Comment: `a <<- whatever` searches the ancestors of the current environment, i.e. here the ancestors of the global environment, and assigns to the first `a` found.  In this case it will find `a` in the attached `x` first.